# Express get URL and delete certain object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Now I'm developing CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) App with Express and LowDB.

And I successfully developed the create and read but Delete Function is not working.

There are detail page like this

[image]

as you can see there are trash can Icon and actually I also have some problem the submit button but It's not important so I just make submit button.

this is the part of the pug file

```
aside#Delete.is-visible
  form(method="post" action='/delete_process')
   input(type='submit')
  a#DeleteButton(role='button')
    img(src='https://png.icons8.com/ios/35/000000/waste-filled.png' id="go_up")
    span.text
      | Delete
      br
      b this
```

detail page have URL (ex: DIR1WTqr2) and it's DB id

and delete Process code is like this.

```
/* Delete Process */
router.post('/delete_process', function (req, res) {
    // GET Delete ID from URL
    let id=req.params.id;

    console.log(id);
    db.get('project').find({
      id: id
    }).remove().write();

});
```

I thought I can get URL and find the data with the id in json file. but It's not working. When I tried to console the req.params.id it said undefined

And I think there are collision with view Detail page because Detail page code is like this.

```
/* GET Detail View Page */
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  // GET URL params and put it into :id
  let id = req.params.id;
  // console.log(id);
  // GET data id to use Object
  let data = db.get('project').find({
    id: id
  }).value();
  // Get github URL
  let url = data.githuburl;
  // Use Request Module to parsing Web page
  request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    };
    // Parsing readme ID in github page
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('#readme').each(function () {
      // save to readme Variable
      let readme = $(this).html();
      // console.log(data);
      // console.log(id);
      res.render('detail', {
        dataarray: data,
        name: data.name,
        url: data.url,
        explanation: data.explanation,
        imgurl: data.imgurl,
        markdown: readme,
        startDate: data.pjdate1,
        endDate: data.pjdate2,
        githuburl: data.githuburl,
        sumlang: data.sumlang
      });
    });
  });
});
```

because of `:id` when I click the /delete_process it goes to detail page I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pug is very specific about your indentation. Your button wasn't contained inside the form - it was a sibling.  Make sure that you've always got two spaces when you want an element to be contained inside another.

Change the pug template to this and the button will submit properly:

```
aside#Delete.is-visible
  form(method="post" action='/delete_process')
    input(type='submit')
      a#DeleteButton(role='button')
        img(src='https://png.icons8.com/ios/35/000000/waste-filled.png' id="go_up")
        span.text
          | Delete
          br
          b this
```

But wait there's more!  You aren't passing the id of the restaurant back with the form.

I can't see how you're using the restaurant id in the pug, but you'll need to add that into the form somehow too.  Let's assume it's a variable in the pug template called `restaurant.id`.

Your node.js route handler is trying to read `req.params.id` which means that it's going to look to the url to get the id of the restaurant.  You can add the id to the request like this:

```
aside#Delete.is-visible
  form(method="post" action='/delete_process/' + restaurant.id)
    input(type='submit')
```

Then, you'll also need to modify your route to include the id parameter:

```
router.post('/delete_process/:id', function (req, res) {
```

A different way to do this would be to add a hidden form field that sends the id with the form ([here's an article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters) that explains this concept).  If you do it this way you can change the form to look like this:

```
aside#Delete.is-visible
  form(method="post" action='/delete_process/' + restaurant.id)
    input(type='hidden' name='id' value= restaurant.id)
    input(type='submit')
```

Then your delete handling route can pick it up like this:

```
router.post('/delete_process', function (req, res) {
    // GET Delete ID from form field
    let id= req.body.id;
```

The first method of passing the id (in the url) is standard for ajax requests, the second method (as a field in the form) is the standard for posting a form.